# Idiom for unintended consequences

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I am looking for a phrase/idiom that expresses the risk of unforeseen consequences of an action. Fake context: Someone develops a treatment for cancer that is later found to cause Alzheimer's. So far, I have found "better the devil you know..." and "robbing Peter to pay Paul." Neither quite get this right.

Comment: The duplicate offers a good discussion. You could also refer to "unforeseen consequences"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiom [out of the frying pan into the fire](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/out-of-the-frying-pan-into-the-fire)   may suggest what you are referring to:

> - Fig.  said when you move from a bad or difficult situation to one that is worse.(Typically: get ~; go ~; jump ~.)

Source: Cambridge Dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Immoral hazard :)

But seriously, "no good deed goes unpunished" sort of works for your example, though not well for the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Reminds me of the title of Edward Tanner's book: *Why things bite back. Technology and the revenge of unintended consequences*".

"Be careful what you wish for" is another one I hear frequently.